# How can I merge across forked repositories, but keep some changes in the local forked repository without it being overwritten, like appsettings

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a base repository that contains the default code. I want to keep changes that is specific to a customer, in another repository, so I forked the base repository and set the base repository as an upstream repository.

In this forked repository, I made the changes relevant for that customer, like GitHub actions for deployment, company logo image, etc.

However, when I now make changes to the base repository and try to merge that in the local repository, the changes get overwritten.

I am working on Windows with code written in Visual Studio.

How do I stop that from happening?

I have tried using .gitattributes files to specify merging strategies, but this seems to be ignored.
Here are the steps I follow in a terminal:

- Ensure there are no outstanding commits in my local repository.
- Fetch upstream (git fetch upstream)
- Pull in the changes from upstream (git merge upstream/main)
- Handle the conflicts.
- Push the changes (git push origin main)

At this point the local changes are "gone".